# Lazy initialization inside willSet issue

Tags: swift, lazy-initialization

I'm trying to create optional array, but I want the initialization to be only before appending element into.

So I wrote:

```
    var names: [String]? {
        willSet {
            if names == nil {
                names = []
            }
        }
    }
```

But I get this error:

> Attempting to store to property 'names' within its own willSet, which
>   is about to be overwritten by the new value

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal is here. But it seems like you don't want the optional array to ever be nil... so why not make it non optional?

Comment: @Fogmeister I want to initialize the array only when using it, it's optional because there is a chance that it will not be initialized in the program at all

Comment: regardless of what you're trying to do, and solely about the error message: ask yourself: **when** is this error happening? It's happening when you're trying to set the new value of `names` to something e.g. to `["John", "Jack"]`...what are the sequence of events? the sequence would be an *attempt* o set it to `[]` which would always and always be overwritten to ["John", "Jack"] because you're writing that in the `willSet`...meaning it will happen before it's set.

Comment: @Honey `the sequence would be an attempt o set it to [] which would always and always be overwritten to ["John", "Jack"] because you're writing that in the willSet` I check before if it's nil, then only set to empty array

Comment: @ULAQ Don't worry about the cost of allocating an empty array – you're attempting to perform a premature optimisation that is adding needless complexity to your code. Just make `names` non-optional, and initialise it with an empty array.

Comment: @ULAQ And rather unsurprisingly, the sdlib already optimises the empty array case – https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift#L71

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a lazy bar then you should do it like...

```
lazy var names: [String] = []
```